# Read JSON File with Express JS

Tags: json, express

I'm having a hard time trying to get one value from a json file. Whatever I change it doesnt work. Can someone please help me and tell me what i am doing wrong? Here's my code

```
app.get('/results', function(req, res){
filePath = '/home/smath/'+req.query.id+'comp.json';
fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
            throw err;
     }
        var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
        var score_comp = jsondata.scorecomplexes;
   });

console.log(score_comp);
var jsonResponse = [];
jsonResponse.push({"text": "Complexes: "+score_comp+"/10"});
res.send(jsonResponse);
});
```

the json file i'm trying to read looks like this :

```
{"complexes":[{"Réponse 1":"a."},
             {"Réponse 2":"a."},
             {"Réponse 3":"c."}],
 "scorecomplexes":2}
```

thanks already for your help !

Comment: Any error? Can you really access that score-comp variable oitside the scope?

Comment: @Nezure i get the error:  "score_comp is not defined" ,and sorry i don't understand your second question ...

Comment: Please check my answer, where I try to explain why you get the "score_comp is not defined". 
See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables "jsondata" and "score_comp" are declared locally for your function passed to app.get.. Therefore they are not accessible outside of that scope.

One solution is to declare the variables outside that "scope" and make the variables global, see example below:

```
//global variables
var jsondata;
var score_comp;

app.get('/results', function(req, res){
filePath = '/home/smath/'+req.query.id+'comp.json';
fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
            throw err;
     }
        jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
        score_comp = jsondata.scorecomplexes;
   });

console.log(score_comp);
var jsonResponse = [];
jsonResponse.push({"text": "Complexes: "+score_comp+"/10"});
res.send(jsonResponse);
});
```